# Multi model data binding

Tags: sapui5

OK, I have a great confusion about data binding in SAPUI5.

After reading [this](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/91/f1156f6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm?frameset=/en/1a/08f70951a744b1a7962b09665cc92f/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/5c/be4e5b4a19479a92b1d32ff23b7b63/plain.htm&node_id=135) and [this](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/91f0f3cd6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) info I still don't know why my code doesn't work.

I define the data and the model in `onInit` function of the controller:

```js
var oControlsData = {
    controls: [
        {control: [
            {title: "Input Filed"},
            {visible: true},
            {iconUrl: "sap-icon://edit"}
        ]},
        {control :[
            {title: "Combo Box"},
            {visible: true},
            {iconUrl: "sap-icon://edit"}
        ]},
        {control :[
            {title: "Radio Button"},
            {visible: true},
            {iconUrl: "sap-icon://bo-strategy-management"}
        ]}
    ]
};

var oControlsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oControlsData);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oControlsModel, "controls");
```

Then, in `onAfterRendering` function I try to bind data from the model to the `sap.m.List` control:

```js
var oList = sap.ui.getCore().byId("controlsList");

var oListTemplate = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
    title: "{title}",
    visible: "{visible}",
    icon: "{iconUrl}"
});

oList.bindItems({
    path: "controls>/controls/control",
    template: oListTemplate
});
```

It seems to me the path is correct, but I still get "No Data" in the control.

What went wrong here?

If I miss something big in understanding data binding process, please give a brief explanation, because every time I have to play with data binding I wonder if it work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path in `bindItems` should be the path to the list of Items.
So in your case `controls>/controls`.

The paths of the properties of the ListItem should then be relative to each object in the list.

```js
sap.ui.getCore().byId("controlsList").bindItems({
    path: "controls>/controls",
    template: new sap.m.StandardListItem({
        title: "{controls>control/0/title}",
        visible: "{controls>control/0/visible}",
        icon: "{controls>control/0/iconUrl}"
    })
});
```

You need the `control/0/` because of your inner array. If you have control over the structure of your data, I would recommend to remove that.

```js
var oControlsData = {
    controls: [
        {
            title: "Input Filed",
            visible: true,
            iconUrl: "sap-icon://edit"
        },
        ...
    ]
};
```

---

On a sidenote, why are you doing databinding in `onAfterRendering`?
This should be done in the View. For example in XML:

```xml
<List items="{controls>/controls}">
    <StandardListItem title="{controls>control/0/title}" visible="{controls>control/0/visible}" icon="{controls>control/0/iconUrl}" />
</List>
```

Comment: This is almost correct, but you forgot to include the model name in the bound template controls :) I.e. `title: "{controls>control/0/title}"` and `<StandardListItem title="{controls>control/0/title}"... `

Comment: @hirse thank you. Your sidenote is also helpful - I have no idea why did I put databinding into controller. I'll change the code.

Comment: @hirse: when using a fix index number (here 0) for the template, the list being rendered will only show the first value (instead of iterating over the array). How can one avoid this behaviour?